# multi comparison in cgridview in yii

Tags: yii, filtering, cgridview

in cgridview there are a blank field to filter the data above every column how can I filter data depend on multi comparison creteria for example I can put >5 in this field in ID column to filter the data to be only records from id 6 and above.
I want to put something like >5 and <10 how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `$filter` instance of `YourModel` and implement custom `search()` method like its shown [here](http://queirozf.com/reminders/yii-cgridview-filter-examples):

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $filter = new YourModel('search');
    $filter->unsetAttributes();
    if (isset($_GET['YourModel']))
        $filter->attributes = $_GET['YourModel'];
    $this->render('yourview', array(
        'filter' => $filter,
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $filter->search(),
    'filter' => $filter
    ...
));
```

As the result, attributes of `$filter` model contain values that user put in filter input fields of `CGridView` and its `search()` method can parse and use these values in any way to create required [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) and then return filtered [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider).

I didn't test it but to filter some attribute `field` of your model one could write something like this:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^(<|>)(.+)$/', $this->field, $matches))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition('field ' . $matches[1] . ' :field');
        $criteria->params[':field'] = $matches[2];
    }
    else
    {
        $criteria->addCondition('field = :field');
        $criteria->params[':field'] = $this->field;
    }

    // TODO: add conditions for other fields

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

If you want to have both `<` and `>` conditions in one filter field it's up to you to decide which format to use and how to parse it to prepare search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use this code:

```
    $matches=array();
    if(preg_match('/(.+)(\s)(.+)/',$this->field,$matches)) {
        $criteria->addCondition("field ".$matches[1]." and field ".$matches[3]);
    } else {
        $criteria->compare('field',$this->field);
    }
```

And in filter input in cgridview i can use "<100 >50" (whitespace character is important in this case)